# GoogleMaps - multiple markers with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a nice google map with some markers on it. I've found some really convinient solution in the web, which covers almost my every need :D I'd like to colorize pin/markers on the map.

Well, tried to make a working jsfiddle, but unfortunately, something went wrong :( so you wouldn't see the map, but there are all codes :)
http://jsfiddle.net/hf37ftra/9/

```
// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['Marker_name', 51.113882,17.070474],
];
```

this part is responsible for showing multiple markers, can I somehow define here the color of the marker (I know it is possible, because I've found tutorials to change ALL the markers colors, but I'd like to make let's say 4-5 different coloured markers)?

Later in the code is part for custom info box for every marker, so maybe it could be done that way :)
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use something like :

```
    var markers = [
      ['Starter', 51.113882,17.070474,'icon1.png'],
    ];
```

and change your constructor to :

```
     [...]
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0],
        icon: markers[i][3]
    });
```

Comment: Wow, 44 second before my own answer! :D

Comment: Cool that you did it on your own ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I love being on stackoverflow, when I can learn everyday something new with just some little help from others :)

```
// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['Title', 51.113882,17.070474, 'http://youriconaddress'],
];
```

and then, in part:

```
// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0],
        icon: markers[i][3] // [3] tells JS to take third 'argument' from markers variable, from each one.
    });
```

That way you can add as many arguments as you want, having a really nice and simple tool to make nicer google maps!

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop:

```
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
```

You can add extra line there:

```
   icon: 'brownMarker.png'
```

Comment: Yeah, I've read API documentation concerning that topic of course :)
However, when you look at the code I've provided, you will notice, that defining a new marker and its info windows is far more convenient than defining every new one. So maybe I've stated question a little wrong - how I can, according to my code, add there some customization for marker colors without too much rewriting the code :)