# How to display multiple colour pins on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am currently displaying markers on a Google Map successfully, but want to overlay a different set of markers in a different colour for something else but I'm a bit stuck on how to do it.

I am getting the data into the `$markers` array from a database as follows:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) 
    {
    $rows[]=$row;
    $markers[$key] = trim($row[12]).','.trim($row[13]).','.trim($row[10]).','.trim($row[9]).','.trim($row[8]).','.trim($row[4]).','.trim($row[6]).','.trim($row[3]); 
    $key = $key +1;
    }
```

Where the `$row[""]` is the data from the database including lat and lon for the marker locations.

The magic then happens in here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?=$api_key?>">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var marker = {};
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: 20.1788823, lng: 13.8262155},
            zoom: 2
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
        var markers = [];
        <?php 
            $counter = 0;
            foreach ($markers as $index => $list){
                   $marker_details = explode(',',$list);
                   echo 'markers["m'.($index-1).'"] = {};'."\n";
                   echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].lat     = '".$marker_details[0]."';\n";
                   echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].lon     = '".$marker_details[1]."';\n";
                   $counter++;
           }
        ?>
        var totalMarkers = <?=$counter?>;
        var i = 0;
        var infowindow;
        var contentString;
        for (var i = 0; i<totalMarkers; i++){
            
            contentString = '<div class="content">'+
                  '<h2 class="firstHeading">'+markers['m'+i].name+'</h2>'+
                  '<div class="bodyContent">'+
                  '<p>'+markers['m'+i].content+'</p>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '</div>';
            
            
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: contentString
            });

            marker['c'+i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers['m'+i].lat,markers['m'+i].lon),

                    icon:   { 
                            url: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"
                            },
                            
                    map: map,
                    title: markers['m'+i].name,
                    infowindow: infowindow
              });
            //console.log(markers['m'+i].lat+','+markers['m'+i].lon);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker['c'+i], 'click', function() {
                    for (var key in marker){
                        marker[key].infowindow.close();
                    }
                    this.infowindow.open(map, this);
                    
            });
        }

      }
      function panMap(la,lo){
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(la,lo));
            
      }
      function openMarker(mName){
          //console.log(marker);
          for (var key in marker){
              marker[key].infowindow.close();
          }
          for (var key in marker){
              
            if (marker[key].title.search(mName) != -1){
                marker[key].infowindow.open(map,marker[key]);
            }
          }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

And finally it is rendered with this:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

I have tried reading the second set of data from another data into `$markers2[$key]` but I'm then stuck at what to do next, I've tried quite a few different things (too many to list here!) but it either fails to render the new markers of fails to render anything at all on the map.

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful. I'm not too familiar with javascript unfortunately.

Comment: A JS script with PHP and data we don't see/have is not a [mcve]. Please read that link and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change color multiple marker in google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805138/change-color-multiple-marker-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: [example categories map with different icon for each category](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GoogleMaps - multiple markers with multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424247/googlemaps-multiple-markers-with-multiple-colors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, the issue was that I was creating another "new" map each time and needed to remove the additional instances of :

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
```

Now the additional markers with the new data display correctly.

Thanks for all the downvotes, it really does concentrate the mind on finding the solution yourself!